# Calculating if I'm going to have my gift swapped

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My company is doing something...strange for the christmas party. Its sort of a yankee swap, but with a twist.

> Roll The Dice Swap!
>
> Roll a 1 – keep your gift
>
> Roll a 2 – steal anyone’s gift
>
> Roll a 3 – everyone passes their gift to the left
>
> Roll a 4 – everyone passes their gift to the right
>
> Roll a 5 – keep your gift
>
> Roll a 6 – steal anyone’s gift

I'm trying to figure out the probability of your gift (assuming you have one already) getting swapped out.
It looks like keeping your gift is 33%, a gift being stolen is 33% and gifts shifting is 33%. What I'd like to do is find out, each round, what the chance is that the gift you have is either shifted away or stolen.

It seems like it would be 1/3 + integral of (dn/(N-n)) for each person after you n out of N people have drawn and assuming axiom of choice of the gift (with respect to motivation to swap) but I can't get the numbers to work out.

Can someone help me specifically understand how to calculate this sort of nonsense?

EDIT: I'm not sure what the plan is. Before we've done an ordinary Yankee Swap where we draw lots for order, then each person either takes a present from the pool or takes someone else's. I would think it works that way with presents shifting only to those who already have presents (effectively the pool of present-holders grows incrementally). Although they could also decide to just randomly assign the presents and then each person in turn rolls the dice. In that case I think the probability would just be 1/3+1/N?

EDIT 2: Lets say that no person ends up with more than one gift.

EDIT 3: For simplicity, I'm assuming each present is equally desirable (knowing my company, its probably booze) and that each person gets one roll of the die. Further, once they get "steal a gift" they get to chose which gift to take.

Comment: For clarity: Under the "steal anyone's gift" rolls, do you steal from everyone with equal probability? Can you steal your own gift? Also, are you assuming gifts are initially given to all $N$ people, and we proceed sequentially with the rolling thereafter? Another variation would be that the gifts are in the middle and we progressively pick gifts (so we can only steal from people who have picked before us), but there is no dice roll for "pick a gift from the middle."

Comment: If you steal a gift, do you have two gifts, or do you swap your gift with theirs?

Comment: I'm going to say when someone steals your gift, they give you what they had before.

Comment: Related: Assuming we pick a gift from the middle before each roll, but then we roll a "shift left" it means the next person (who has not yet picked from the middle) gets a free gift _and_ a chance to pick from the middle, meaning that person will have two gifts before his/her roll of the dice.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the powers that be may not have thought through this scheme.

Comment: The "steal anyone's gift" seems to mean "choose a person with whom to swap gifts", right? And do I get to choose, or is the person determined randomly somehow? Is it reasonable to assume that each person plays to maximize the quality of their gift? Do all players have the same utility for all gifts (i.e., is there a "best" gift, and a second-best, and so on, that all agree on)? I'm wondering whether, when you get a "swap gifts" roll (assuming you get to choose) it's always best to swap with the best gift...not clear to me. Also: how long does the dice game go on? One round? Many rounds?

Comment: It seems to me that once you've said all gifts are equally desirable (and I assume that this means that swap-partners are chosen randomly) this is amenable to a pretty simple simulation...once we know how many rounds of dice-rolling happen.

Comment: number of rounds would be 1 roll per person until everyone has gotten a turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The odds that you'll lose your current item in a given roll are in $(1/3,2/3]$ with the upper bound hit for $n=2$ players.

Assume $n\ge2$ players. On any given turn, there is a $\frac13$ chance of losing your gift through a rotation. Assuming that on a stealing roll a player is forced to exchange their gift with that of another, and assuming this decision is uniformly drawn from the remaining $n-1$ players, then there is a $\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right)$ chance of losing through a steal every round. So the odds you lose your current gift each round is the sum
$$\frac13\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)$$.

I'd say the next step is to consider the odds of losing your gift after one entire cycle of dice rolls (i.e. everyone in the game's circle gets to roll the dice once). This seems like combining a drunken walk problem with a bit of teleportation due to the stealing roll.